# Nginx+React working on k8s cluster, but not in local

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the same nginx configuration to serve a React based application in both local and k8s cluster. It is working perfectly fine on the cluster, but not on localhost:3000

Following is nginx.conf file:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Docker.frontend:

```
# ====== CONFIGURE =======
FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 node:18 as build-step

WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY ./package.json /app/
COPY ./package-lock.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

# ====== NGINX FOR FRONTEND =======
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY --from=build-step /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

# ====== EXPOSE PORT AND RUN COMMAND =======
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  backend:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.backend
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
    restart: always
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.frontend
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - ./frontend/package.json:/app/package.json
    depends_on:
      - backend
    restart: always
```

I also have set homepage path in package.json as follows:

```
  "homepage": "/apples/oranges/webapp"
```

I am able to access the application on:
https://mywebsite.com/apples/oranges/webapp

But not on:
http://localhost:3000/apples/oranges/webapp

I am running the application in local like this:

- docker-compose build --no-cache
- docker-compose up

And then accessing: http://localhost:3000/apples/oranges/webapp

What could be wrong here?

Comment: What error or result do you get?  The one obvious thing here is that it looks like your backend is listening on port 8000, but the `proxy_pass` directive doesn't include that port number so it will use the default HTTP port 80.

Comment: I do not get any error. But is just does not load.

Comment: Network call says 500 error